# Get url without querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL like this:

`http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye`

I want to get `http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx` from it.

Can you tell me how can I get it?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can use `System.Uri`

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye");
string path = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", url.Scheme, 
    Uri.SchemeDelimiter, url.Authority, url.AbsolutePath);
```

Or you can use `substring`

```
string url = "http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye";
string path = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?"));
```

EDIT: Modifying the first solution to reflect brillyfresh's suggestion in the comments.

Comment: url.AbsolutePath only returns the path portion of the URL (/mypage.aspx); prepend url.Scheme (http) + Uri.SchemeDelimiter (://) + url.Authority (www.somesite.com) for the full URL that you wanted

Comment: Uri.GetLeftPart method is simpler as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188096/truncating-query-string-returning-clean-url-c-sharp-asp-net/1188180#1188180

Comment: The `substring` method will give error if there's no Query string. Use `string path = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?") > 0? url.IndexOf("?") : url.Length);` instead.

Answer (score 438):

Here's a simpler solution:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye");
string path = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

Borrowed from here: [Truncating Query String & Returning Clean URL C# ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188096/truncating-query-string-returning-clean-url-c-asp-net/1188180#1188180)

Comment: One line version: `return Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);`

Comment: `uri.GetComponent(` is another awesome method for getting parts of a Uri.  I didn't know about these two until now!

Answer (score 44):

This is my solution:

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.Query, String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 38):

Good answer also found here [source of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175559/how-to-get-the-url-without-querystring-values-in-asp-net)

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)
```

Answer (score 36):

Succinct solution:

```
Request.RawUrl.Split('?')[0];
```

Comment: I like this just for the fact you can use it without a full uri.

Comment: Keep in mind that `RawUrl` will get the URL _before_ URL rewrites, so perhaps use `AbsoluteUri`?

`Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]`

Answer (score 16):

My way:

```
new UriBuilder(url) { Query = string.Empty }.ToString()
```

or

```
new UriBuilder(url) { Query = string.Empty }.Uri
```

Comment: This is what i use for NET Core 1.0 project because it has not method `Uri.GetLeftPart`. Latest version of NET Core (1.1) should have that method (cant confirm because i'm not on net core 1.1 for now)

Comment: I like this one because building URIs is exactly what the UriBuilder is for. All the other answers are (good) hacks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` to get the page name, and `Request.Url.Authority` for the host name and port. I don't believe there is a built in property to give you exactly what you want, but you can combine them yourself.

Comment: It is giving me /mypage.aspx , not what I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

`System.Uri.GetComponents`, just specified components you want.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye");
uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer | UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx
```

Answer (score 7):

**Split() Variation**

I just want to add this variation for reference.  Urls are often strings and so it's simpler to use the `Split()` method than `Uri.GetLeftPart()`. And `Split()` can also be made to work with relative, empty, and null values whereas Uri throws an exception.  Additionally, Urls may also contain a hash such as `/report.pdf#page=10` (which opens the pdf at a specific page).

The following method deals with all of these types of Urls:

```
   var path = (url ?? "").Split('?', '#')[0];
```

**Example Output:**

- null ---> empty
- empty ---> empty
- http://domain/page.html ---> http://domain/page.html
- http://domain/page.html?q=100 ---> http://domain/page.html
- http://domain/page.html?q=100#page=2 ---> http://domain/page.html
- http://domain/page.html#page=2 ---> http://domain/page.html
- page.html ---> page.html
- page.html?q=100 ---> page.html
- page.html?q=100#page=2 ---> page.html
- page.html#hash ---> page.html

Comment: I'm rather shocked this hasn't gotten any upvotes until my own. This is a great solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an extension method using @Kolman's answer. It's marginally easier to remember to use Path() than GetLeftPart. You might want to rename Path to GetPath, at least until they add extension properties to C#.

Usage:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.somewhere.com?param1=foo&param2=bar");
string path = uri.Path();
```

The class:

```
using System;

namespace YourProject.Extensions
{
    public static class UriExtensions
    {
        public static string Path(this Uri uri)
        {
            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
            }
            return uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Request.RawUrl.Split('?')[0]
```

Just for url name only !!

Answer (score 1):

```
    string url = "http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye";
    string path = url.split('?')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Silverlight:

```
string path = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple extension, as a few of the other answers threw null exceptions if there wasn't a `QueryString` to start with:

```
public static string TrimQueryString(this string source)
{ 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            return source;

    var hasQueryString = source.IndexOf('?') != -1;

    if (!hasQueryString)
        return source;

    var result = source.Substring(0, source.IndexOf('?'));

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var url = Request.Url?.AbsoluteUri.TrimQueryString()
```

Answer (score 0):

.net core get url without querystring

```
var url = Request.GetDisplayUrl().Replace(Request.QueryString.Value.ToString(), "");
```

Answer (score -1):

simple example would be using substring like :

```
string your_url = "http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye";
string path_you_want = your_url .Substring(0, your_url .IndexOf("?"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var canonicallink = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
urlString=Request.RawUrl.ToString.Substring(0, Request.RawUrl.ToString.IndexOf("?"))
```

from this: http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye
you'll get this: mypage.aspx

Answer (score -3):

```
this.Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, this.Request.RawUrl.IndexOf('?'))
```