# How to get complete URL of browser in UrlRewriting using C#

Tags: c#, url

I have used URL rewriting. I have one question is that I have URL like

```
http://localhost/learnmore.aspx
```

This is URL overwriting so I want this complete URL so I have coded like this.

```
string url=Request.RawUrl;
```

After this code I got `/learnmore.aspx` in url variable but I want the complete URL `http://localhost/learnmore.aspx`

How can I do this?

Comment: don't see how this is related to Url Rewriting, you just wont a full URL ? Request.Url.AbsoluteUri ?

Comment: Yes but if i use the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri then i get http://localhost/Default.aspx?pageid=25 so its not useful for me and thats due to URL ReWritting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get host and scheme this way :

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

With this you will get :

> http://localhost/

and then you can append RawUrl

Answer (score 3):

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost/learnmore.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /localhost/learnmore.aspx

string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost
```

EDIT: To remove query string items: (found from [Get url without querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630249/get-url-without-querystring))

```
var uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
string path = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

OR

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye");
string path = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", url.Scheme, 
    Uri.SchemeDelimiter, url.Authority, url.AbsolutePath);
```

OR

```
string url = "http://www.somesite.com/mypage.aspx?myvalue1=hello&myvalue2=goodbye";
string path = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?"));
```

Comment: I have used the URLRewritting here so i will get something like this if i used the above three ...i get http://localhost/Default.aspx?pageid=25 but i want http://localhost/learnmore.aspx

Comment: @KartikPatel, I have edited the answer, just try the solution now

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get the base url :

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + 
    Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` would do the trick.