# how to manipulate the URL path in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following path:

> -http://localhost/portal/reportview.aspx

but I need to retrieve the first 3 parts:

> -http://localhost/portal/

Ive tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart();` with no luck.

Comment: If you place a debug break on the Request.Url you can see all the items that can give you , like the `.Path` and can do the job. Is faster than make a question.

Comment: This question question might be interesting for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630249/get-url-without-querystring

Comment: Always the first three parts or remove the "reportview.aspx"? Or to put it in a different way, what if the url is `http://localhost/portal/sub/page.aspx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
string s = "http://localhost/portal/reportview.aspx";
string y = string.Format("{0}//{2}/{3}/",s.Split('/'));
```

Comment: Split finds an empty string between the `//`, so either shift the indexes or use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries in the Split.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring.

```
string str = "http://localhost/portal/reportview.aspx";

string left = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("/"));
```