# Get current URL but excluding some parts

Tags: c#, asp.net

The current URL looks like: http://mycompany.com/jobs/java-developer.aspx#.U9-RH2OTLfA

I need to get the part before the #, so it's gonna be: http://mycompany.com/jobs/java-developer.aspx

How can I do that in code behind?

Comment: Asked and answered many times.  Please research before posting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630249/get-url-without-querystring

Comment: @RickS That's not a query string though, it's an anchor/fragment/tag.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Referenced post will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Uri` class:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://mycompany.com/jobs/java-developer.aspx#.U9-RH2OTLfA");
var result = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = "http://mycompany.com/jobs/java-developer.aspx#.U9-RH2OTLfA";
string path = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("#"));
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://mycompany.com/jobs/java-developer.aspx#.U9-RH2OTLfA");
string url = myUri.Host + myUri.LocalPath;
```

you can create uri with string then get the parts

Answer (score 0):

```
    private String getGoodString(String url)
    {
         return url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("#") - 1);
    }
```

This will return everything up to but not including the # symbol in your string. Assuming you have a # to signal when to stop getting the string of the URL. Otherwise if there are multiple #. You can use **`lastIndexOf`**, or **`firstIndexOf`** if you need to "trim the fat".