# how to get current page from url excluding query string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to get current page URL excluding query string parameters. 
My URL is like this https://mywebsite.com/myproject/detailspage?id=2812

I want to get only https://mywebsite.com/myproject/detailspage.

I tried this but not helped.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Please any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get url without querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630249/get-url-without-querystring)

Answer (score 2):

`Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)`

Comment: for some reason Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) gives me http link instead https link. I don't know what i am missing.