# Uri.GetComponents return query params even if its not requested

Tags: c#, .net, uri, uribuilder

I am trying to extract the path of my PathString without the query parameters.
So I did the following:

```cs
var ps = new PathString("/someapi/wayne/insane?param=1234&ups=134");
var u = new UriBuilder();
u.Path = ps;
// Built Uri: http://localhost/someapi/wayne/insane%3Fparam=1234&ups=134
u.Uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.Unescaped).Dump();

// returns: "someapi/wayne/insane?param=1234&ups=134"
```

I'd have expected it will return: `/someapi/wayne/insane`
Is it supposed to work that way?
Is there another way to get just the path?

I found this: [Get url without querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630249/get-url-without-querystring), pointing out to use `GetLeftPart`, which resulted in the same string.

Comment: Well you are using the `UriBuilder` wrong. The `Path` property should only have the actual path, not query parameters inside it. It seems it's not actually verifying that. If you set the `Query` property separately you get correct results https://dotnetfiddle.net/9HdGwU

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant way to do it, but it works for all cases I can think of for now:

```cs
var ps = new PathString("/someapi/wayne/insane?param=1234&ups=134");
var u = new Uri("http://localhost" + ps.Value);
u.LocalPath.Dump();
```

Interestingly the PathString needs to be resolved to string by using the Value property.